# need assist using regex_replace with wstring

Tags: c++, stl

I want to use regex_replace like the example linked here using using string/c-string (3) version: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/regex_replace/

The problem is I don't understand templates and the regex classes well enough to use regex_replace per example, but with a wide string. I saw the wregex, but I'm not seeing how I can use it.

The idea is to take a string regex_{13E008E3-EEE7-4AC3-B9F1-E353DB67EDFD} and turn it into status_{13E008E3-EEE7-4AC3-B9F1-E353DB67EDFD}

```
wstring statusDataName;
wstring key              = wstring(L"regex_");
wstring repl             = wstring(L"status_");
TCHAR dataName[MAX_STR]  = {0};
statusDataName = regex_replace(wstring(dataName), key,  repl);
```

> error C2784:
>   'std::basic_string<_Elem,std::char_traits<_Elem>,std::allocator<_Other>>
>   std::regex_replace(const _Elem *,const
>   std::basic_regex<_Elem,_RxTraits> &,const _Elem
>   *,std::regex_constants::match_flag_type)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const _Elem *' from
>   'std::basic_string,std::allocator>'
>   error C2784:
>   'std::basic_string<_Elem,std::char_traits<_Elem>,std::allocator<_Other>>
>   std::regex_replace(const _Elem *,const
>   std::basic_regex<_Elem,_RxTraits> &,const
>   std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits1,_Alloc1>
>   &,std::regex_constants::match_flag_type)' : could not deduce template
>   argument for 'const _Elem *' from
>   'std::basic_string,std::allocator>'
>   error C2784: 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits1,_Alloc1>
>   std::regex_replace(const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits1,_Alloc1>
>   &,const std::basic_regex<_Elem,_RxTraits> &,const _Elem
>   *,std::regex_constants::match_flag_type)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::basic_regex<_Elem,_RxTraits> &' from
>   'std::wstring' error C2784: 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits1,_Alloc1>
>   std::regex_replace(const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits1,_Alloc1>
>   &,const std::basic_regex<_Elem,_RxTraits> &,const
>   std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits2,_Alloc2>
>   &,std::regex_constants::match_flag_type)' : could not deduce template
>   argument for 'const std::basic_regex<_Elem,_RxTraits> &' from
>   'std::wstring' error C2780: '_OutIt
>   std::regex_replace(_OutIt,_BidIt,_BidIt,const
>   std::basic_regex<_Elem,_RxTraits> &,const _Elem
>   *,std::regex_constants::match_flag_type)' : expects 6 arguments - 3 provided error C2780: '_OutTy *std::regex_replace(_OutTy
>   (&)[_OutSize],_BidIt,_BidIt,const std::basic_regex<_Elem,_RxTraits>
>   &,const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc>
>   &,std::regex_constants::match_flag_type)' : expects 6 arguments - 3
>   provided error C2780: '_OutIt
>   std::regex_replace(_OutIt,_BidIt,_BidIt,const
>   std::basic_regex<_Elem,_RxTraits> &,const
>   std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc>
>   &,std::regex_constants::match_flag_type)' : expects 6 arguments - 3
>   provided

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Working variant:

```
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>

using std::wstring;

int main()
{
    wstring dataName = L"regex_{13E008E3-EEE7-4AC3-B9F1-E353DB67EDFD} ";

    wstring key              = wstring(L"regex_");
    wstring repl             = wstring(L"status_");
    wstring statusDataName = std::regex_replace(dataName, std::wregex(key),  repl);
    std::wcout << statusDataName << L"\n";
}
```

Comment: this got me stuck too! Thanks!